# Scroll to DOM element created in list bound to observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a knockout click binding on an element. Inside of the click handler I add an element to an observableArray which is bound to a `<ul>`. When an item is added to this observableArray I'd like to be able to scroll the page so that the newly-added `<li>` is at the top of the page. Is there any way to do this? My thought was to get the `<li>` and then use the `scrollIntoView` method, but I can't figure out how to get the DOM element from the data. Seems like I need something the reverse of `ko.dataFor`. Here's a JSFiddle with a TODO showing what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/klinden/rkLZ6/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: myStuff">
    <li data-bind="text: name, setFocus: {}" "></li>
</ul>
```

And script code:

```
var ctr = 2;

ko.bindingHandlers.setFocus = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(element).offset().top}, 500);
    }
};


var vm = {
    myStuff: ko.observableArray([
        {name: 'foo1', desc: 'bar1'}
    ]),
    addFooBar: function() {
        this.myStuff.push({name: 'foo' + ctr, desc: 'bar' + ctr});
        ctr++;
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```